# Is it possible to change server_tokens directive not in nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

I need to uncomment the following line in nginx.conf

```
#server_tokens off;
```

But I don't want do it in nginx.conf directly so is it possible to make this change in another place like in some config files placed at /etc/nginx/conf.d/ directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be changed in either http, server or location block.

```
syntax:     server_tokens on | off;
default:    server_tokens on;
context:    http, server, location
```

> Enables or disables emitting nginx version in error messages and in the “Server” response header field.

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens

Comment: I need to change it for all locations

Comment: Yes. Just add `server_tokens off;` to all the location blocks that you want to change.

Comment: my Node app ignores the config, you guys know any reason ? I've just created a .platform folder then another folder called nginx with a nginx.conf file inside